# Are conference "proceedings" always first given as verbal presentations at the conference?

Tags: proceedings

...Or are some of them just papers that were submitted?

I always thought the "proceedings" of a conference were a reflection of the talks at the conference, not merely submitted articles.

Please help me clear this up.  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "first given"?

Comment: Normally proceedings of a conference are papers already discussed as talk or posters at that event. I believe that if one cannot present because of major forces or so, the proceeding will be published anyway.